# Select option in a list without ID tag

Tags: html, vbscript

Can someone please tell me how to select the option "Expanded Fields/Comma Separated" from the list below in VBScript? I've searched all over but most everything I found has to do with using `getelementbyID` which won't work in this case.

```html
<form name="mainform" action="proxy.aspx?page=download&amp;sub=submit" method="post">
<table width="100%">            
<tbody><tr id="headertext">             
<td colspan="2">                
<div id="PageHeader">                   
<div id="Title">Select Download File Type</div>             
<div id="Help">
<a href="javascript:openHelp(4010);">Help</a></div>
</div>          
 </td>      
</tr>   
<tr id="headertext2" style="display: none;">        
<td class="MainHeaderFont" colspan="2">         
<div>Download Request Submitted</div>           
</td>       
</tr>   
<tr><td colspan="2">

<select name="version">
<option value="300" selected="">Standard/Tab Delimited</option>
<option value="310">Standard with Card Code/Tab Delimited</option>
<option value="400">Expanded Fields/Comma Separated</option>
<option value="VbV">Expanded Fields with CAVV Response/Comma Separated </option>
</select>

</td>           
</tr>       
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't select by ID then you have to select by name or tag name and identify the relevant element from the result set by other criteria, for instance the element's text.

In this case the element you need to fetch is `<select>`, because you want to iterate over its child elements (`<option>`), particularly if you want to change the selection, because you have to unselect the currently selected option for that.

Since your `<select>` element has a `name` attribute you can use `getElementsByName` like this:

```
For Each option In doc.getElementsByName("version")(0)
  If option.innerText = "Expanded Fields/Comma Separated" Then
    option.Selected = True
  Else
    option.Selected = False
  End If
Next
```

`doc` is a variable referencing the `document` property of the page.

Since the `name` attribute doesn't have to be unique `getElementsByName` returns a list, so you need to pick the element you want to process (in this case the first one, at index 0).